# Deny character if preceded by another specific character

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regex-lookarounds, python-re

I have a question about python, specifically about the regex topic.

Assuming I have the following rule:

```
[^\$\?\¡]*
```

That is, one that allows all but a few characters.

I need to add to that rule a condition similar to the following:
Deny a character only if it is preceded by another specific character.

An example would be not allowing the = character if it is preceded by;

```
something;=somethingElse -> something; somethingElse
something=somethingElse -> something=somethingElse
```

The problem is that when I try to use the lookbehind inside the square brackets functionality it doesn't work as expected.

```
[(?<!\;)\=\$\?\¡]*
```

Is there a way to write such a rule? I looked in several places but I did not find anything similar, surely there is something but in the way I looked for it nothing appears.

Comment: Can you give a few example of what you expect? You have put the lookbehind inside the character class, so it will try to match the individual characters of the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character classes match single characters, do not add lookbehinds there. Use alternation:

```
(?:[^$?¡=]|(?<!;)=)+
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/C0Ufp0/1). The expression finds one or more characters other than `$?¡=` or `=` with no semi-colon before it.

Comment: I do not understand why the negative vote, since I clarified everything at the end of the post, but thanks for the response.